# iframe src change on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change src of iframe after button click. i cant find a solution

```
     <iframe id="Pencere" name="window" src="https://stackoverflow.com/" ></iframe>
     <input id="number" name="Number" type="text" >            
     <input id="button" class="button button1" type="button" value=" Jump " onclick="javascript:jump()"/>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function jump()
      {              
        var number= document.getElementById("number").value;
        var url = "https://www.otherwebsite.com/"+number+"/1";
        document.getElementById("Pencere").src = url;
      }  
</script>
```

Result after button click: [image: result after button click]

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to go to an other website in iframe with an input variable on button click

Comment: You are doing good. but first, check if there is exist the URL which you provide in the `var url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function newSrc() {
  var e = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
  var newSrc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("MyFrame").src=newSrc;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://beamtic.com/" style="width:450px;height:450px;overflow:scroll;" id="MyFrame"></iframe>
<select id="MySelectMenu">
  <option value="https://beamtic.com/">Beamtic</option>
  <option value="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">Wiki</option>
</select>
<button onClick="newSrc();">Change Iframe Src</button>
```

Hope you are looking for this kind of functionality